# Polymer binding data to element loaded with innerHTML

Tags: javascript, data-binding, polymer

I am using [Polymer](http://polymer-project.org) for a project. I have html elements that are loaded in via `this.innerHTML`. I want to bind data from these elements to the main page. I have no idea whether this is possible or not. This is the setup: I have a main app that binds elements to the `html` attribute of my `<html-echo>` element. This element should then load the html using `.innerHTML` (otherwise the html isn't parsed). From that element that gets injected I want to bind its data. Is this possible?

**main-app**

```
<polymer-element name="main-app">
    <template>
        <html-echo html="{{htmlToBeEchoed}}"></html-echo>
    </template>
    <script>
        Polymer('main-app', {
            htmlToBeEchoed = "<test data='{{data}}'></test>";
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**html-echo.html**

```
<polymer-element name="html-echo" attributes="html data">
    <script>
        Polymer('html-echo', {
          htmlChanged: function() {
            // WARNING: potential XSS vulnerability if `html` comes from an untrusted source :()
            this.innerHTML = this.html;
          }
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

**test.html**

```
<polymer-element name="test" attributes="data">
    <script>
        Polymer('test', {
            data: 5
        });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use injectBoundHTML. From https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/607:

```
/**
* Inject HTML which contains markup bound to this element into
* a target element (replacing target element content).
* @param String html to inject
* @param Element target element
*/
injectBoundHTML: function(html, element)
```

In the polymer element, instead of

`el.innerHTML = html;`

do

`this.injectBoundHTML(html, el);`

Comment: Is there an equivalent for Polymer 1.0?

Comment: I need this too in Polymer 1.0. This is a huge problem if it's not going to become available. Setting via innerHTML is not something modern web developers can live without!

Comment: @Clay I am a bit late to the party but perhaps you can set the inner-h-t-m-l attribute on the element?  <div inner-h-t-m-l="{{html}}"></div>

Comment: @Bram absolutely brilliant! Never thought that was a option. Works perfectly. This should be posted as a proper answer and upvoted. I only happened to dig deeper and found your comment